# How to get the pod resource usages using java library kubernetes-client?

Tags: java, scala, kubernetes

I am trying to get pod resource usages using java library kubernetes-client. Both Class NodeMetrics and ContainerMetrics have getUsage() function, but Class PodMetrics does not. So what should i do to get pod resource usages?

The program I wrote is in scala language, so the answer would be better if scala or java were used. Thanks in advance.

```scala
import io.kubernetes.client.Metrics
import io.kubernetes.client.custom.NodeMetricsList
import io.kubernetes.client.openapi.{ApiClient, Configuration}
import io.kubernetes.client.util.Config

import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters.{ListHasAsScala, SetHasAsScala};

object MetricsMonitor {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val client: ApiClient = Config.defaultClient()
    Configuration.setDefaultApiClient(client)

    val metrics: Metrics = new Metrics(client)
    val list: NodeMetricsList = metrics.getNodeMetrics
    val items = list.getItems.asScala.toArray

    for (item <- items) {

      println(item.getMetadata.getName)
      println("------------------------------")
      for (key <- item.getUsage.keySet.asScala.toArray) {
        println("\t" + key)
        println("\t" + item.getUsage.get(key))
      }
      println()
    }

    val podMetricsList = metrics.getPodMetrics("boc").getItems.asScala.toArray

    for (item <- podMetricsList) {

      println(item.getMetadata.getName)
      println("------------------------------")
      if (item.getContainers == null) {
        // Continue to the next iteration
      } else {
        for (container <- item.getContainers.asScala.toArray) {
          println(container.getName)
          println("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-")
          for (key <- container.getUsage.keySet.asScala.toArray) {
            println("\t" + key)
            println("\t" + container.getUsage.get(key))
          }
          println()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Provide the code that you have tried with.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sum the metrics of each container of the pod?